# Adding normal text after endnotes

Tags: microsoft-word, endnote

Is it possible to add normal text after endnotes in MS Word?

I found this  http://word.tips.net/T000513_Adding_Information_after_the_Endnotes.html but it requires that sections are not used.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is an "official" way to do it. But I hope someone can come up with a better way than the following...

As you say, the method you referenced does not work if you already have a multi-section document (because it relies on being able to gather the endnotes at the end of section 1, then insert the following text in section 2).

I have not used the following technique in a real-world scenario. It may get you close to what you need, but it requires some manual intervention.

Specify that the Endnotes are at the end of the document.

Insert the text that you want to follow the Endnotes. (The Endnotes will now be in the wrong place).

Select the Endnotes and insert a Bookmark (let's call it "endnotes").

Click where you want the Endnotes to appear and use Ctrl-F9 to insert a pair of the special field code braces {}.

Between the braces, type

```
REF endnotes \*mergeformat
```

so you have

```
{ REF endnotes \*mergeformat }
```

Select the field and update it using F9. If you use Alt-F9 to toggle between field code display and field result display, with any luck you will see the endnotes in the place where you want them to be. (Problem 1 that I have not researched is that this display may not be an accurate reflection of the real Endnotes).

Problem 1 is that the original Endnotes will still display at the end of the document as well. To deal with that, reselect the endnotes at the end of the document, and set the font to "Hidden". However, when you next update the { REF endnotes } field, the result of that will also be hidden. So what you do is select the *result* of the { REF } field, and format it as not hidden. Then, when you update the field, its result should not be hidden.

Problem 2 is that there is still a separator at the end of the document. You cannot select the separator in the usual way, but you cannot hide it.

How to do that depends on your version of Word, but for example in Word 2010, you cango to File-Options->Quick Access Toolbar, select "All Commands" in the "Choose Commands From" dropdown, locate and select "View Endnote Separator" in the list of command, and click the Add button to add it to the Quick Access Toolbar (QAT). While you are there, you could usefully add the "View Endnote Cont Notice" and "View Endnote Cont Separator" commands to the QAT.

Then click on the "View EndNote Separator" button the the QAT, and you should see a new pane that allows you to modify the separator. Typically, it will contain a number of underline characters. Move to the end of those underlines, and backspace until they are gone.

If your Endnotes flow over one page, you may need to delete the "Endnote Cont Notice" and "Endnote Cont Separator" in the same way.

Problem 3 is that your Ref field does not include the Endnote Separator, Endnote Cont notice or EndNote Cont Separator, even when you do not delete them. You could insert your own Endnote Separator at the end of the document and before the { REF } that generates a copy of your Endnotes, , but keeping the others would be much more difficult.

problem 4 is that when you insert a new Endnote, you would have at the very least to update your REF field by selecting it and updating it. But if the Endnote precedes the first Endnote in the document or follows the last one, you may need to go and reselect the original Endnote text and re-insert the "endnotes" bookmark to ensure that your { REF } field references *all* the Endnotes.